# I am confused by "with each case specifying the behavior of the system" contained in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I am an English learner. Recently I encountered a sentence that is confusing to me, as shown below:

> With this approach the functionality of the system is specified through use cases, **with each case specifying the behavior of the system** when a user interacts with it for achieving some goal.

I know every single word in the sentence, including "use cases". Yet, "**with each case specifying the behavior of the system**" seems like an unfinished sentence to me. How should I comprehend this quoted sentence?

In my head, this quoted sentence should better be "**with each case the behavior of the system can be specified**".

Comment: I edited the title, so users can see what the problem is with a glance. If I have it mistaken, please edit and explain which words or noun phrase etc. confuses you the most.

Comment: I'm sure you understand the meaning of each individual word, but it would be nice if you *did* say that in your question. And at least attempt to say what you think the author is saying–I'd also recommend you to mention what the context is and to provide the title of the text/book, IN the question. Not in comments, which people often ignore.

Comment: Are you confused about what a "use case" is? See for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case)

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous. I have re-edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"With each case specifying the behavior of the system" is not a complete sentence, but it doesn't have to be, because it is only a *clause* within a complete sentence. In fact you didn't even quote the full clause, which is "With each case specifying the behavior of the system **when a user interacts with it**."

The meaning is: There are a number of different use cases. Each use case describes what the system does when there is a specific input/interaction. When you look at all the cases together, you can see they define the system as a whole.